# Upgrade the pip to the specified version

Tags: python, pip

From [pip document](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip):

I know in Mac we can use:

```
pip install -U pip
```

to upgrade the pip to newest version.

But how can we upgrade pip to the specified version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like this.

```
pip install -U pip==(version of pip you want)
```

I don't know if it will work or not you can always try.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip==(version of pip you want)` works.